# I am missing something with Django's url paths

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, url, django-2.0

I have an app in django that has a webpage with buttons to travel to another page via a menu and 8 hrefs. When I travel to the first page and try to click on another, I will encounter a 404 error.

```
Page not found (404)
http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.html/contact
```

Here is my url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('index.html/', views.homepage),
     path('contact.html/', views.contact),
     path('about.html/', views.about),
]
```

Views as well

```
def customers(request):
    return render(request, 'customers.html')

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html')

def contact(request):
    form_class = ContactForm
    return render(request, 'contact.html', {
        'form': form_class,
    })
```

Settings is unchanged.
I believe that is all there is in making a URL path for a webpage.

I do not want `http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.html/contact` I want `http://127.0.0.1:8000/index` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact`
How do I keep my URLs basic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your urls.py should contain the URL patterns. These can be different from the name of the files you put in your templates/ directory. As such, your patterns should not have ".html" extensions if you want to access without the ".html" in the URLs:

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('index/', views.homepage),
     path('contact/', views.contact),
     path('about/', views.about),
]
```

When you click on some "Contact" link on the index page, you seem to build a URL relative to the index page, not the root of your site. In your templates, the href attribute of links should start with "/", e.g.:

```
<a href="/contact/">Contact</a>
```

instead of

```
<a href="contact/">Contact</a>
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand what each file does now.

Comment: @Sleepy-Z Welcome to SE. If you are happy with the answer, please mark it as "accepted". See https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Just remove .html from the urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('index/', views.homepage),
     path('contact/', views.contact),
     path('about/', views.about),
]
```